# How can i pass Data into my SQLite-Database

Tags: sqlite, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello there :)  I am pretty new to programming and I recently started an IONIC App. However I got stuck. I want to do something like a phone book where you can get random JSON contacts and save them to your sqlite database.

I got this:

```
import { Storage ] from '@ionic/storage';
    @component({
        selector: 'page-home'
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
});

export class HomePage {

  posts: any;
  persons: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {

  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.posts = data;
 });

}

//here i would like to recieve the data from the tapped Item

  setData(){
    console.log();
        this.storage.set('myData', this.posts);
        console.log(this.posts);
  };


  getData(){
     this.storage.get('myData').then((data) => {
       if (data !=null){
         console.log(data);
       }
    })
  };
}
```

Here is the View:
When i click / tap the save-button i would like to store the values in my sqlite-database and display them in my "local contacts".

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
                <ion-list>
                    <ul><h1>{{post.name}}</h1></ul>
                    <ul><p>{{post.username}}, {{post.email}}</p></ul>
                    <ul><p>phone: {{post.phone}}</p></ul>
                    <button ion-button (click)="setData()">Set Data</button>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

Maybe someone faced similar problems and can help me with this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best way to handle persistent storage with Ionic is using [ionic-storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage).**

Ionic Storage is a package created and maintained by the ionic team to abstract development from the specifics of each browser or platform and automatically use the best storage solution available.

## 1. Installing Dependencies

In your case for SQLite you need to first install the dependencies for both Angular and Cordova:

`npm install @ionic/storage --save`

and

`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`

Then edit your NgModule declaration in `src/app/app.module.ts` to add `IonicStorageModule` as an import:

```js
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: '__mydb',
      driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'],
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## 2. Inject Storage into your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}
}
```

## 3. Storing data in SQLite

Whenever you access storage, make sure to always wrap your code in the following:

```
storage.ready().then(() => { /* code here safely */});
```

#### 3.1 Saving a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.set('some key', 'some value');
});
```

#### 3.2 Retrieving a value

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
  storage.get('age').then((val: string) => {
      console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
});
```

#### 3.3 Deleting a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.remove('key').then((key: string) => { /* do something after deletion */})
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It was helpful, but not exactly what i tried to ask for. Maybe my description was too inaccurate.

I did all the steps down to 3. The problem is, that I don't know how to access the data of the tapped Item. 

when I tap a single contact I want the object of this particular contact to be send to the saveContact() function.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question was a bit misleading, maybe you should modify OP to convey your question better for future readers. Now in order to pass the particular contact object into the setData() function just change your code into this `<button ion-button (click)="setData(post)">Set Data</button>`. The `post` is already defined in your *ngFor so you can use it as an argument into the function call. If this answers your question please vote up the comment as well as the original answer.

Comment: Yes this is the answer i was looking for. Thank you very much. For some reason i cant upvote your comment and the answer because i have not enough reputation. I will do it when i reach 15 reputations ;)

Comment: Glad I could help, bud. :)