# Geo-location in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm working on Ionic app, which should show users on the map by their current geo-location.

- For example, User 1 can turn on GPS, and other Users can see him on
  the map after opening a MapComponent. For example, GeoService can fetch current data of the Users's location, on safe it frequently in db (once a minute, for example), and other users, when open MapComponent, can fetch all of data from db collection, and see the Points on the map.

What plugins should I use, or tutorials to archive it? How to get access of the GPS location. How to enable and disable it?

Comment: Why are people down-voting this? It's a legitimate question. If you are willing to down-vote please at least state the reason why or the infringement and explain top the OP how he could have avoided this or stated it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) will be a life saver for you.**

> Ionic Native is a TypeScript wrapper for Cordova/PhoneGap plugins that make adding any native functionality you need to your Ionic mobile app easy.

### Geolocation

Depending on how accurate you want the geolocation ping to be and how energy you want it to use you can either go for [`Background Geolocation`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/) (cheap) or [`Geolocation`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/).

### Map Component

In order to display a map with markers on it you should use the [`Google Maps`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) plugin.

### Local Data Cache

You will probably also need a way to cache locally any data you get from the backend (or anything else). The best and easiest way to go about it is using [`ionic-storage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44374300/5015955).

### Developing using native cordova plugins

In any case, since all these APIs are operating on top of Cordova, you should only test this functionality in an actual device or in an emulator. Of course when geolocation is involved, you cannot go run around the block each time you make a code change so I strongly advise you to [mock](https://www.techiediaries.com/mocking-ionic-native-3-x-plugins/) these plugins during development.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I as well found this tutorial, which works perfect, if some one will be interested late..   https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-to-an-ionic-2-application/.  Maninak, what do you think about a way to represent data for other through fetching cords from db?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately not very clearly put. If you are asking of a way to represent data, there is example code in the Google Maps plugin link on how to display a marker on the map. If you are asking how to sync and fetch data from DB, you could create a simple node api, or better yet (and simpler to sync) use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). I do feel, though, that we are starting to get out of the scope of your original post. You should maybe start a new one for the specifics of those (if you don't find enough help online).

Comment: yep, it was about data representing. Kind of of topic... I just wanted to ask is this way of representing, which I described, is fine for this case.

Comment: I take it then that my previous answer directing you to the use of Markers tutorial has answered your question? As I said, yes you could fetch the coordinates from the database. And it's best that you don't connect directly to the database but through and API, for security reasons.

Comment: [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147533) to mark an answer as correct. :)